# Click not working using variable in testcomplete

Tags: javascript, testcomplete, aliases, template-aliases

Click not working using variable in testcomplete as following.

```
var okbtn= "Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK";
  okbtn.ClickButton();
```

while direct click without variable is working fine as following.

```
 Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK.ClickButton();
```

I am using testcomplete 10 and java script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your 1st example okbtn is a string,you should do

```
var okbtn= Aliases.LateralData_Applications_Dashboard.LoginForm.btnOK
```